# 2 or more iOS devices with different versions of iOS (7.x 9.x) & same App, will keep which App versions on iTunes sync?

Tags: itunes, applications, ios, versions

I have several iOS devices with iOS 7.x to 9.x installed and they are all synced with iTunes on my computer. How can I manage the differing versions of my suite of apps on these devices when iTunes keeps only the latest versions of these apps? Some later versions of these apps just will not run on iOS 7.x.

How would it resolve this conflict given that it is managing both devices; both different iOS versions and App versions suitable for each.

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense please clarify

Comment: Do you mean to say: **I have several iOS devices with iOS 7.x to 9.x installed and they are all synced with iTunes on my computer. How can I manage the differing versions of my suite of apps on these devices when iTunes keeps only the latest versions of these apps? Some later versions of these apps just will not run on iOS 7.x.**

Comment: @IconDaemon yes. Anyway to keep both versions of apps available in iTunes?

Comment: You might want to try creating separate user accounts on this single laptop, one user per iOS version. These accounts' iTunes might be able to store the older versions of the apps. Worth a try.